# Synchronized charts example with Highstock crashes with "Cannot read property 'category' of undefined"

Tags: highcharts

I want the functionality of the "Synchronized charts" example, but with Highstock. But when trying to accomplish this, I get "highstock.src.js:9991 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'category' of undefined"

This also holds directly for the example: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/synchronized-charts doesn't work when converted to Highstock: http://jsfiddle.net/9gq47g0w/

(Since StackOverflow demands me to post some code along with the fiddle, here's from Highstock, noting the point where it crashes with **):

```
    /**
     * Refresh the tooltip's text and position.
     * @param {Object} point
     */
    refresh: function (point, mouseEvent) {
        ...
        // shared tooltip, array is sent over
        if (shared && !(point.series && point.series.noSharedTooltip)) {
            ...
            textConfig = {
                x: ** point[0].category, ** <- here!
                y: point[0].y
            };
           ...
        }
        ...
    },
```

Comment: I think that this example can help you with your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/ZArZM/20/

Comment: You can also see this example: http://jsfiddle.net/vw77cooj/20/ with similar functionality to what you would like to achieve

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński: http://jsfiddle.net/ZArZM/20 - Works for one serie and for tooltip but it does not work for two series. Missing the marker:  http://jsfiddle.net/ZArZM/315/

Comment: You need to rebuilt the function responsible for synchronizing your tooltip: http://jsfiddle.net/ZArZM/316/

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński: Put it as an answer, so that I can accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can find an example of synchronized highstock charts: 
http://jsfiddle.net/vw77cooj/20/

This example is using custom functions for synchronizing extremes and tooltips on charts:

```
  function syncExtremes(e) {
    var thisChart = this.chart;

    if (e.trigger !== 'syncExtremes') { // Prevent feedback loop
      Highcharts.each(Highcharts.charts, function(chart) {
        if (chart !== thisChart) {
          if (chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes) { // It is null while updating
            chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(e.min, e.max, undefined, false, {
              trigger: 'syncExtremes'
            });
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }

$('#container').bind('mousemove touchmove touchstart', function(e) {
  Highcharts.each(Highcharts.charts, function(chart) {
    event = chart.pointer.normalize(e.originalEvent);
    point = chart.series[0].searchPoint(event, true);

    if (point) {
      point.onMouseOver(); // Show the hover marker
      chart.tooltip.refresh(point); // Show the tooltip
      chart.xAxis[0].drawCrosshair(event, point); // Show the crosshair
    }
  });
});
```

In case of having multiple series on your chart you may change function responsible for synchronizing your tooltip:

```
  function syncTooltip(container, p) {
    var i = 0,
      j = 0,
      data,
      series,
      points = [];
    for (; i < chartSummary.length; i++) {
      if (container.id != chartSummary[i].container.id) {
        series = chartSummary[i].series
        Highcharts.each(series, function(s) {
          Highcharts.each(s.data, function(point) {
            if (point.x === p && point.series.yAxis.options.index !== 1) {
              points.push(point)
            }
          })
        });
        chartSummary[i].tooltip.refresh(points);
      }
    };
  }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZArZM/316/

Comment: searchPoint is internal Highcharts method and that is the reason why it is not described in Highcharts API.

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński you example is pretty cool but for N charts it doesn't work... :'( http://jsfiddle.net/5rmw0or8/ Many issues with selection point and sometines no tooltip (or just one in it)

Answer (score 0):

For a nice working example on Highstock, please follow this example with MouseOver and MouseOut:

```
var onMouseOver = function onMouseOver() {
    var x = this.x,
      interactedChart = this.series.chart,
      points = [],
      charts = Highcharts.charts,
      each = Highcharts.each;
    each(charts, function(chart) {
      if (chart !== interactedChart) {
        each(chart.series, function(series) {
          each(series.data, function(point) {
            if (point.x === x && point.series.yAxis.options.index !== 1) {
              points.push(point)
            }
          })
        });
        each(points, function(p) {
          p.setState('hover');
        });
        chart.tooltip.refresh(points);
      }
    });
  }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ska1r5wq/

You can avoid many tooltip issues from examples provided on the web.

Source : https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/6595